# How to prevent EF to create localdb if connectionString is wrong (or missing at all)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I've a group of modules (persistence, service, mvc web, tools...) sharing common configuration parameters and allowing local overrides for particular environment/developer in app.config/web.config files using pre-build events.

Persistence module is based on EF 6.1 Code First with default initialization strategy i.e. *CreateDatabaseIfNotExists*.

Everything works smoothly except connection string is error or missing at all and **update-database** command is executed: if this is the case, EF ignores error connection string, somehow builds its own one and silently creates a new LocalDb database in current user folder.

How to prevent this behaviour? I want to create a new database, but only if there is a valid connection string. On invalid connection string an exception should be thrown.

Comment: You can change default connection factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the default behaviour, Then you should change the default connection factory:

```
 <entityFramework>

    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">

      <parameters>

        <parameter value="v11.0" />

      </parameters>

    </defaultConnectionFactory>

  </entityFramework>
```

So if you don't provide the connection string, EF uses that as a default connection string. So you can change it easily:

```
<entityFramework>

    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">

      <parameters>

        <parameter value="Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

      </parameters>

    </defaultConnectionFactory>

  </entityFramework>
```

[more info.](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/15/a-troubleshooting-guide-for-entity-framework-connections-amp-migrations.aspx)

Comment: I've tried to remove <parameter> element and it seems that still works. Is there any possible pitfall if it is omitted?